# Equality with alternating harmonic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$u_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$$
$$I_n = \int_0^1 \! \dfrac{x^n}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

### What I need to prove

I would like to prove, without saying that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} u_n = \ln{2}$, that $$u_n - \ln{2} = (-1)^{n+1} I_n$$

### What I tried

I tried saying that $$I_n = \int_0^1 \! \dfrac{x^n + 1}{1+x} - \dfrac{1}{x+1} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \! \dfrac{x^n + 1}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d}x - \ln{2}$$

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \! (~\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (-x)^k~) \, \mathrm{d}x - \ln{2}$$

$$I_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{-(-1)^{k+1}}{k + 1} - \ln{2}$$
$$I_n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{k}}{k + 1} - \ln{2}$$

I have the feeling this is the right way to go, as it gives me an alternating series left ($u_n$) and right ($I_n$ after what I did) and some logarithm, but I am stuck here. Could anyone help me?

Comment: the geometric series starts with $k=0$, not with $k=1$

Comment: You have some problems with the signs, otherwise you basically have the proof down. You only have $\dfrac{1+x^n}{1+x} = 1 - x + \dotsc \pm x^{n-1}$ for odd $n$. But that's where the fact that you look at $(-1)^{n+1} I_n$ is helpful. You get $\dfrac{1-(-x)^n - 1}{1 - (-x)}$.

Comment: @tired thanks I'll edit it, I meant 0 of course.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer thanks I forgot that part of the geometric identity, I'll try to fix it and get back to you